# Location Manager- function does'nt select provider

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

My app needs a location and when GPS provider is ON, everything working correctly = I'm getting my location. Unfortunately, when GPS is off my app can't reach Network provider even if it's on and I don't have a clue why.

After this, there's news on the screen `Disabled provider Network` (In this time network is avalible) and my app crashes.

Code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);; 

        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latituteField = "Location not available";
            longitudeField = "Location not available";
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                400, 1, this);
        needGPS = true;
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (needGPS == false || starttime == 0)
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onPause();
        if (needGPS == false || starttime == 0)
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
        double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField = (String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField = (String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Why Network provider is disabled every time, even when network on my Galaxy SII is ON?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a permission problem.
Open AndroidMaifest.xml and make sure you have

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I've got even more: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, CCESS_NETWORK_STATE